# android setAlpha slow

Tags: android, view, alpha

If I do `setAlpha(0.5f)` on a few (image) views, my app gets horribly slow, at least on my Android 4.+ tablets.

If I remove the `setAlpha` calls, the app (scrolling and paging) works smoothly.

Is there an alternative/faster method for making my views semitransparent?

Answer (score 0):

If you provide some code I can try to see what is wrong, there is no reason and explanation of slowing the app, there must be other thing in the code/project/layouts to make your app work slower

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a custom view that calls Canvas.saveLayerAlpha() before drawing its children. Android 3.0+ versions there is a View.setAlpha() api..

Also you can create transparent or opaque background.Here is the link
http://zaman91.wordpress.com/2010/03/22/android-how-to-create-transparent-or-opeque-background/

Hope it helps.